# Где можно временно развернуть динамический сайт (сервер на GO, бд — MS sql server), чтобы сделать его публичным?

Tags: веб-программирование, sql-server, сервер, веб-сервер, hosting

Подскажите, пожалуйста, сайт (хостинг или облако).

Так как это учебный проект, то нужен бесплатный пробный период и временный домен.

Comment: Учебный проект можно развернуть и на своём собственном компьютере, если он у вас есть.

Comment: Мне нужен доступ к нему с других компьютеров в интернете

Comment: Домашние интернет-провайдеры часто предоставляют публичный IP-адрес, иногда даже бесплатный, и если ваш провайдер из таких, то и доступ к вашему компьютеру тоже вполне будет.

Comment: https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 1):

https://www.heroku.com/

Heroku - условно бесплатный хостинг